# Service worker notification promise broken?

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) I see that `showNotification` returns a promise that *should* resolve to a `NotificationEvent`.

> ## Syntax
>
> ​ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification(title,
>   [options]).then(function(NotificationEvent) { ... });
>
> #### Returns
>
> A Promise that resolves to a NotificationEvent.

However I have set it up [here](https://laff.manix.info/index/locate), the notification is being sent and all but if you look at the console you will notice that `event` is undefined.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js');

Notification.requestPermission(function (result) {
    if (result === 'granted') {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
            registration.showNotification('Laff', {
                body: 'Hello, you have unread mesages!',
                icon: '/apple-touch-icon.png',
                tag: 'test'
            }).then(function(event){
                console.log(event);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I need to get a hold of the notification, which I thought I could do from `event.notification` but since `event` is undefined I don't really know what to do.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same event is just null in promise resolve.

Comment: @deathangel908 check out the accepted answer, you can listen for notification click. I don't know why this is not as per documentation.

Comment: I need the notification object, In my particular case, I want to close notification by timeout.

Comment: not sure what's up with the docs, or what's up with the current spec, but you can get a list of all showing notifications using [ServiceWorkerRegistration.getNotifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean of getting hold on notification ?
if you are looking to capture an event when user will click on notification, you can do by adding listener.

add return .

```
return registration.showNotification('Laff', {
```

catch the event on notificationClick:

```
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

        var tag = event;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: The `self` in this answer is the service worker, not necessarily the code that shows the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a problem in the docs, the `showNotification` method doesn't return a `NotificationEvent` object.

If you don't want to wait for the click, you can use the `getNotifications` method. Here's a code to close the notification after 3 seconds.

```
self.registration.showNotification(...).then(() => {
    self.registration.getNotifications({tag: ...}).then(notifications => {
      setTimeout(() => notifications[0].close(), 3000);
    });
  }
})
```

More informations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications

Comment: Maybe you'd like to update your answer, now the docs seem to have been updated. The showNotification method returns a promise that resolves to undefined. Regards.